# ConsumerWidget does not detect state changes

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I'm writing flutter with riverpod.

I decided to test the login behavior with Firebase and created a simple login app. I created the following Widget.

repository: https://github.com/tbt0127/login_test_app

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:login_test_app/controllers/sign_in_controller.dart';
import 'package:login_test_app/models/app_user_info_model.dart';

final _emailTextEditingController = Provider.autoDispose<TextEditingController>(
  (_) => TextEditingController(),
);

final _passwordTextEditingController =
    Provider.autoDispose<TextEditingController>(
  (_) => TextEditingController(),
);

class SignInPage extends ConsumerWidget {
  const SignInPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    // Provider
    final signInController = ref.read(signInControllerProvider);
    final appUserInfoModel = ref.watch(appUserInfoModelProvider);
    final emailController = ref.watch(_emailTextEditingController);
    final passwordController = ref.watch(_passwordTextEditingController);

    return Center(
      child: appUserInfoModel.when(
        data: (data) {
          if (data == null) {
            return Column(
              children: [
                TextField(
                  controller: emailController,
                ),
                TextField(
                  controller: passwordController,
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    signInController.signIn(
                        emailController.text, passwordController.text);
                  },
                  child: const Text('SignIn'),
                ),
              ],
            );
          } else {
            return Column(
              children: [
                Text(data.name),
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    signInController.signOut();
                  },
                  child: const Text('sign out'),
                )
              ],
            );
          }
        },
        error: (e, s) => Text(e.toString()),
        loading: () => const Text('Loading'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`appUserInfoModel` is defined like below

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:login_test_app/entities/app_userinfo.dart';
import 'package:login_test_app/repositories/auth_repository_impl.dart';

final appUserInfoModelProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<AppUserInfoModel, AsyncValue<AppUserInfo?>>(
        (ref) => AppUserInfoModel(ref));

class AppUserInfoModel extends StateNotifier<AsyncValue<AppUserInfo?>> {
  AppUserInfoModel(this.ref) : super(const AsyncValue.data(null)) {
    debugPrint("init");
    _userStreamSubscription = ref.listen(authUserProvider, (previous, next) {
      next.when(data: (data) {
        debugPrint("data: ${data?.uid ?? "null"}");
        if (data != null) {
          debugPrint("data: ${data.uid}");
          state = AsyncValue.data(
              AppUserInfo(id: data.uid, name: data.email ?? "empty"));
        } else {
          debugPrint("null");
          state = const AsyncValue.data(null);
        }
      }, error: (error, stackTrace) {
        debugPrint("error");
        state = AsyncValue.error(error, stackTrace);
      }, loading: () {
        debugPrint("loading");
        state = const AsyncLoading();
      });
    });
  }

  final Ref ref;
  ProviderSubscription<AsyncValue<User?>>? _userStreamSubscription;

  Future<void> signIn({
    required String email,
    required String password,
  }) async {
    final authRepository = ref.watch(authRepositoryImplProvider);
    state = const AsyncLoading();

    state = await AsyncValue.guard(() async {
      try {
        await authRepository.signIn(
          email: email,
          password: password,
        );
      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
        debugPrint(e.code);
      }
      return null;
    });
  }

  Future<void> signOut() async {
    final authRepository = ref.watch(authRepositoryImplProvider);
    state = const AsyncLoading();

    state = await AsyncValue.guard(() async {
      try {
        await authRepository.signOut();
      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
        debugPrint(e.code);
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    debugPrint("dispose");
    _userStreamSubscription?.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

However, even after entering the correct information and pressing the login button, I am returned to the form after the Loading message.

Please tell me what is wrong and why the change is not detected. By the way, if I restart the app after a successful login, the email address is displayed and I am logged in.

---

**EDIT 230423**

I wrote `AppUserInfoModel` by `AsyncNotifier`. But the problem did not solved.

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:login_test_app/entities/app_userinfo.dart';
import 'package:login_test_app/repositories/auth_repository_impl.dart';

final appUserInfoModelProvider =
    AsyncNotifierProvider<AppUserInfoModelNotifier, AppUserInfo?>(() {
  return AppUserInfoModelNotifier();
});

class AppUserInfoModelNotifier extends AsyncNotifier<AppUserInfo?> {
  @override
  FutureOr<AppUserInfo?> build() {
    ref.listen(authUserProvider, (previous, next) {
      next.when(data: (data) {
        debugPrint("data: ${data?.uid ?? "null"}");
        if (data != null) {
          debugPrint("data: ${data.uid}");
          state = AsyncValue.data(
              AppUserInfo(id: data.uid, name: data.email ?? "empty"));
        } else {
          debugPrint("null");
          state = const AsyncValue.data(null);
        }
      }, error: (error, stackTrace) {
        debugPrint("error");
        state = AsyncValue.error(error, stackTrace);
      }, loading: () {
        debugPrint("loading");
        state = const AsyncLoading();
      });
    });
    return null;
  }

  /// サインインする
  Future<void> signIn({
    required String email,
    required String password,
  }) async {
    final authRepository = ref.watch(authRepositoryImplProvider);
    // サインイン結果をローディング中にする
    state = const AsyncLoading();

    // サインイン処理を実行する
    state = await AsyncValue.guard(() async {
      try {
        await authRepository.signIn(
          email: email,
          password: password,
        );
      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
        debugPrint(e.code);
      }
      return null;
    });
  }

  Future<void> signOut() async {
    final authRepository = ref.watch(authRepositoryImplProvider);
    // サインイン結果をローディング中にする
    state = const AsyncLoading();

    // サインイン処理を実行する
    state = await AsyncValue.guard(() async {
      try {
        await authRepository.signOut();
      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
        debugPrint(e.code);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using legacy StateNotifier instead of modern Notifier-based providers?

Comment: thanks. There are no reason, but I found some articles which uses StateNotifier. I will try Notifier, but is it possible to solve the problem by using Notifier?

Comment: Yes, the notifiers and providers introduced in Riverpod 2 completely replace the functionality of everything prior.  A Notifier can act as both a change notifier (using triggered notifyListeners() or a state notifier (using updates to the state variable).  So with the six new classes: [Async|Stream]Notifier[Provider], you cover everything available before.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz I wrote by `AsyncNotifier` but the problem didn't solved. I think the part of the build function that calls the watch function in the build function is suspect, but what else could be wrong? (I added the URL of the repository where I put all the code.)

Comment: ↑
× watch function
◯ listen function

Answer (score 0):

In the end, don't let StreamProvider mediate with AsyncNotifier.

1. refer directly to StreamProviderw for sign-in state linkage
2. the state of the sign-in process is exposed in AsyncNotifier

The code now works in this way.

repo: https://github.com/tbt0127/login_test_app/tree/fix_repo